# How can I change the size of this box? (CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

http://geodit.com:8000/test

If you search something. Then click a result. You'll see a white bubble pop up on the map.

How can I use CSS to over-ride this an make it smaller?  It's too big!

Comment: the complete map or the bubble?

Comment: I suggest quickly setting `DEBUG = false` in your Django site. It is **very** vulnerable at the moment.

Comment: The bubble. can I make the bubble smaller? Or disappear?

Comment: You may want to put stress testing on the to-do list.

Comment: I want the bubble to be smaller, or even disappear

Comment: The popup will grow to fit the content you provide if you style the content with smaller font size or less data it will shrink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got it right, you are talking about balloon on the map, and unfortunately you **can not** change its size with help of css, because balloon size is hardcoded in style attribute of balloon container (div element):

```
<div style="width: 247px; height: 96px;">
```

that can not be overriden, only with help of javascript, if you get this div you can change its size (ballonContainer refers to that div):

```
ballonContainer.style.width = "150px";
ballonContainer.style.height = "50px";
```

but you will be forced to change also other inner elements size (their size is also hardcoded in style attribute).

**Update**

> I want the bubble to be smaller, or even disappear

well, if you don't need that balloon (aka info window), then do not create it, I just see this line in your javascript:

```
gInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
```

would not it help you? Or you mean something else?

Also you can set maxWidth option of [info window](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#InfoWindows) to limit width of that window, something like that:

```
gInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow( { maxWidth: 150 } );
```

InfoWindow options are described also [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindowOptions)

Comment: I don't want the bubble. But I still want the map to move to the place when a search result is clicked.

Comment: You can do it manually. When user clicks on result you should know its coordinates, just use panTo(latLng:LatLng) method of the Map object